# How to get further detail of table using with keywork in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

I have a `one to many` relation based on two tables `users` and `games`.There is also a **pivot table** `users_games` (linking `user_id` to `games`).

I am trying to fetch a single record based on `game_id` and `user_id` using the script below

```
$GameInfo = User::with(['games' => function ($query) use($request)
        {
            $query->where('game_id', $request->game_id);
        }])->whereHas('games', function ($query) use($request)
        {
            $query->where('game_id', '=', $request->game_id);
        })->find(request()->user()->id);
```

Following is the response of the script above (I am using the `API` Resource)

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "eum",
            "type_id": 2,
            "created_at": "2018-10-30 11:23:28",
            "updated_at": "2018-10-30 11:23:28",
            "pivot": {
                "user_id": 2,
                "game_id": 4
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Actully now I want to fetch `highscore` of that game also which is stored inside the `user_games` table. I tried a lot but still fail to get the desired result.

I would like to request you to kindly guide me how I can do that. I would appreciate it.

Comment: Is `highscore` saved on the database or a accessor (e.g `getHighScoreAttribute')?

Answer (score 1):

In your eloquent relationship, you can use the `withPivot()` function :

```
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role')->withPivot('column1', 'column2');
```

but it will always return the pivot column, if you want to do it only in your current Query, you might do this :

```
  $GameInfo = User::with(['games' => function ($query) use($request)
    {
        $query->withPivot('highscore')->where('game_id', $request->game_id);
    }])->whereHas('games', function ($query) use($request)
    {
        $query->where('game_id', '=', $request->game_id);
    })->find(request()->user()->id);
```